# Iterate through columns and list all columns where a record has a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following table:

```
ID    Group   Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    ... ColN
------------------------------------------------------
1     AAA     foo     bar
2     AAA     123     far             baz
3     BBB
4     CCC     345     123
5     AAA                     caz
```

For each `Group`, I need to find out in what `Col`umns it has a value. I do not care about the values themselves.

Example:

- `Group` AAA has 3 `ID`s in it: `1, 2, 5`. `ID` 1 has a value in `Col1, Col2`. `ID` 2 has a value in `Col1, Col2`. `ID` 5 has a value in `Col3` so in total, `Group` AAA has values in `Col1, Col2, Col3`

The output should then be like this (also listing `Group`s that have no value for any `Col`umn as `null`:

```
Group    Cols
------------------------------
AAA      Col1; Col2; Col3;Col4
BBB      null
CCC      Col3
```

I have hundreds of columns, and hundred of thousands of records.

Can anyone help me get started? I don't know how I can dynamically iterate through all the column names and list them.

Comment: This, honestly, sounds like an XY Problem. The fact that you want to iterate is a problem unto itself (SQL works in sets, not iteratively). If you have hundreds of columns with the same piece of data being represented them that suggests you have a large normalisation design flaw.

Comment: Yes, I do, but it is a table I have no control over but have to work with :)

Comment: *"I have no control over"* but *someone* does and if this is a question that's asked often, and the table really is an badly de-normalised as your question suggests, then they should be fixing it.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Comment: Unfortunately, I've just finished writing a solution for 2017+, so you'll have to convert it to SQL Server 2016 and prior.

Comment: Shouldn't `'AAA'` have a value of `'Col1; Col2; Col3; Col4'`? For ID `2`, it has a value for `Col1`, `Col2`, **and** `Col4`. Why is `Col4` not counted?

Comment: @Larnu -- you are correct! My mistake. Will correct now.

Comment: Whenever you have a table design with "ColN" as part of it, you've done something very wrong with your schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the OP's comment that they have 100's of columns, this suggests that they need a dynamic Solution. I finished this solution just as the OP commented that they are using 2016, so this will *not* work on 2016. They OP will need to convert this to the older `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF` method instead of using `STRING_AGG`.

Other than that, this works:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO


CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ID int,
                            [Group] char(3),
                            Col1 char(3),
                            Col2 char(3),
                            Col3 char(3),
                            Col4 char(3));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES(1,'AAA','foo','bar',NULL,NULL),
      (2,'AAA','123','far',NULL,'baz'),
      (3,'BBB',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
      (4,'CCC','345','123',NULL,NULL),
      (5,'AAA',NULL,NULL,'czx',NULL);
GO

--Hard coded example, to get the idea correct first
WITH UnPvt AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           YT.[Group],
           V.ColumnName
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(N'Col1',Col1),
                            (N'Col2',Col2),
                            (N'Col3',Col3),
                            (N'Col4',Col4))V(ColumnName,ColumnValue)
    WHERE V.ColumnValue IS NOT NULL)
SELECT YT.[Group],
       STRING_AGG(U.ColumnName,'; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY U.ColumnName) AS Cols
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Group] FROM dbo.YourTable) YT
      LEFT JOIN UnPvt U ON YT.[Group] = U.[Group]
GROUP BY YT.[group]

GO

--Dynamic Solution
DECLARE @SchemaName sysname = N'dbo',
        @TableName sysname = N'YourTable';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);
DECLARE @Delimiter nvarchar(50) = N',' + @CRLF + N'                           ';

SET @SQL = N'WITH UnPvt AS(' + @CRLF +
           N'   SELECT DISTINCT' + @CRLF +
           N'          YT.[Group],' + @CRLF +
           N'          V.ColumnName' + @CRLF +
           N'   FROM dbo.YourTable YT' + @CRLF +
           N'        CROSS APPLY (VALUES' + 
           (SELECT STRING_AGG(N'(N' + QUOTENAME(c.[name],'''') + N',' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N')',@Delimiter) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY C.[name])
            FROM sys.schemas s
                 JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                 JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.OBJECT_ID
            WHERE s.[name] = @SchemaName
              AND t.[name] = @TableName
              AND C.[name] NOT IN (N'ID',N'Group')) + N')V(ColumnName,ColumnValue)' + @CRLF +
           N'    WHERE V.ColumnValue IS NOT NULL)' + @CRLF +
           N'SELECT YT.[Group],' + @CRLF +
           N'       STRING_AGG(U.ColumnName,''; '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY U.ColumnName) AS Cols' + @CRLF +
           N'FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Group] FROM dbo.YourTable) YT' + @CRLF +
           N'      LEFT JOIN UnPvt U ON YT.[Group] = U.[Group]' + @CRLF +
           N'GROUP BY YT.[group];';

PRINT @SQL;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=69fe74b24da70a5a9d85d91db2f3b5ea)

Note that this **assumes** that all columns (apart from `ID` and `Group`) have the same data type as well.

*Edit: Sigh... `FOR XML PATH` solution:*

```
DECLARE @SchemaName sysname = N'dbo',
        @TableName sysname = N'YourTable';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);
DECLARE @Delimiter nvarchar(50) = N',' + @CRLF + N'                           ';

SET @SQL = N'WITH UnPvt AS(' + @CRLF +
           N'   SELECT DISTINCT' + @CRLF +
           N'          YT.[Group],' + @CRLF +
           N'          V.ColumnName' + @CRLF +
           N'   FROM dbo.YourTable YT' + @CRLF +
           N'        CROSS APPLY (VALUES' + 
           STUFF((SELECT @Delimiter + N'(N' + QUOTENAME(c.[name],'''') + N',' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N')'
                  FROM sys.schemas s
                       JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                       JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.OBJECT_ID
                  WHERE s.[name] = @SchemaName
                    AND t.[name] = @TableName
                    AND C.[name] NOT IN (N'ID',N'Group')
                  ORDER BY c.[name]
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,DATALENGTH(@Delimiter)/2,N'') + N')V(ColumnName,ColumnValue)' + @CRLF +
           N'    WHERE V.ColumnValue IS NOT NULL)' + @CRLF +
           N'SELECT YT.[Group],' + @CRLF +
           N'       STUFF((SELECT N''; '' + ColumnName' + @CRLF +
           N'              FROM UnPvt U' + @CRLF +
           N'              WHERE U.[Group] = YT.[Group]' + @CRLF +
           N'              ORDER BY U.ColumnName' + @CRLF +
           N'              FOR XML PATH(''''),TYPE).value(''.'',''nvarchar(MAX)''),1,2,N'''') AS Cols' + @CRLF +
           N'FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Group] FROM dbo.YourTable) YT' + @CRLF +
           N'GROUP BY YT.[group];';

PRINT @SQL;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `concat_ws()`:

```
select t.grp,
       concat_ws(',',
                 (case when max(col1) is not null then 'col1' end),
                 (case when max(col2) is not null then 'col2' end),
                 . . .  -- fill in the logic for the rest of the columns
                ) as columns
from t
group by grp;
```

Note:  `concat_ws()` was introduced in SQL Server 2017.  You can do something similar in older versions.

Answer (score 1):

Performance will be bad, but this works generically:

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE (ID INT,[Group] VARCHAR(10),Col1 VARCHAR(10),Col2 VARCHAR(10),Col3 VARCHAR(10),Col4 VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES
 (1,'AAA','foo','bar',NULL,NULL)
,(2,'AAA','123','far',NULL,'baz')
,(3,'BBB',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
,(4,'CCC','345','123',NULL,NULL)
,(5,'AAA',NULL,NULL,'caz',NULL);
```

--the query

```
SELECT rw.query('for $n in * return concat(",",local-name($n))').value('.','nvarchar(max)')
FROM
(
SELECT * 
FROM @mockupTable t
FOR XML PATH('row'),TYPE
) A(x)
CROSS APPLY A.x.nodes('/row') B(rw);
```

The idea in short:

We transform the table to XML. Using `SELECT *` will result in a XML with named elements. That's the *hook* for the generic grip to the column names.

The second thing to know: By default, NULL values will be omited by default within XML.

The result reflects the "filled" columns.

The intermediate XML looks like this (just non-NULL values are represented):

```
<row>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Group>AAA</Group>
  <Col1>foo</Col1>
  <Col2>bar</Col2>
</row>
<row>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <Group>AAA</Group>
  <Col1>123</Col1>
  <Col2>far</Col2>
  <Col4>baz</Col4>
</row>
<row>
  <ID>3</ID>
  <Group>BBB</Group>
</row>
<row>
  <ID>4</ID>
  <Group>CCC</Group>
  <Col1>345</Col1>
  <Col2>123</Col2>
</row>
<row>
  <ID>5</ID>
  <Group>AAA</Group>
  <Col3>caz</Col3>
</row>
```

### UPDATE Closer to your expected output

Try this to get ID and Group in your result

```
SELECT  rw.value('(ID/text())[1]','int') ID
       ,rw.value('(Group/text())[1]','varchar(10)') [Group]
       ,rw.query('for $n in *[local-name() ne "ID" and local-name() ne "Group"] return concat(",",local-name($n))').value('.','nvarchar(max)')
FROM
(
SELECT * 
FROM @mockupTable t
FOR XML PATH('row'),TYPE
) A(x)
CROSS APPLY A.x.nodes('/row') B(rw);
```

The result

```
ID  Group   usedColumns
1   AAA     ,Col1 ,Col2
2   AAA     ,Col1 ,Col2 ,Col4
3   BBB 
4   CCC     ,Col1 ,Col2
5   AAA     ,Col3
```

### UPDATE 2 Your grouped result

You can try this to get a grouped result fully generically

```
SELECT C.gr.value('text()[1]','varchar(100)')
      ,C.gr.query('for $n in row/*[local-name() ne "ID" and local-name() ne "Group"] 
                   return <n>{local-name($n)}</n>')
           .query('for $n in distinct-values(n/text()) 
                   return concat(",",$n)')
           .value('.','nvarchar(max)')
FROM
(
SELECT * 
FROM @mockupTable t
FOR XML PATH('row'),TYPE
) A(x)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT A.x.query('for $gr in distinct-values(/row/Group/text())
                               return <gr>{$gr}{/row[Group=$gr]}</gr>
                               ')) B(gr)
CROSS APPLY B.gr.nodes('/gr') C(gr);
```

The result

```
AAA     ,Col1 ,Col2 ,Col3 ,Col4
BBB     
CCC     ,Col1 ,Col2
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I get an error, however: `Cannot find either column "rw"  or the user defined function or aggregate "rw.query", or the name is ambiguous` and `A has more columns than specified in the column list`?

Comment: @Pr0no Can you execute this against my mockup table (just copy my full sample)?

Comment: I then get the same error (red underlined in SSMS) but I can still run it and have as output:

`,ID ,Group ,Col1 ,Col2
,ID ,Group ,Col1 ,Col2 ,Col4
,ID ,Group
,ID ,Group ,Col1 ,Col2
,ID ,Group ,Col3`

Comment: @Pr0no My updated statement comes closer to your exepcted output... You will have to adapt this to your actual needs...